# HTML & JS pagination

Tags: javascript, jsp, pagination, jquery-pagination

I'm working on a JSP project that has a container to show different tables using tabs same as shown in the following picture.**[strong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLyi3.png)**

What i want to do is making a pagination method using HTML or JAVASCRIPT to put only 10 table's records in each page.
Taking into consideration that this table is a HTML table filled using JSP commands, also all tables placed in tabs are contained in the container. Which means each table must have a pagination bar.
Thank you.

Comment: Tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 1/ If you are using Mysql db you can do pagination with servlets that control the number of data 
2/ you can use Display tag library